# Aggregating large matrices

Tags: r

I have matrix A, and I want to create matrix B where:

column 1 = column 1 of matrix A

column 2 = an aggregation of two columns, where column 1 of matrix A is aggregated with whichever column of matrix A it is correlated most with

column 3 = an aggregation of three columns, where the aggregated result (column 2 of matrix B) is aggregated with whichever column of A it is correlated most with (aside from the column from matrix A already included, this one has been removed from matrix A)

etc.

I loop the calculation for the correlation, where I calculate all correlations in each iteration. This works for low values of r and n (I chose low values in this example for the sake of simplicity), but takes very long with larger data sets. Is there a faster/more efficient way of doing this? Preferably a method where I wouldn't have to calculate all the correlations in each iteration. I've tried functions such as `bigcor()`, but without success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move this outside the for-loop. It doesn't depend on `i`: `maxcor <- names(which.max(sapply(A[,-1, drop=F], function(x) cor(A[, 1], x) )))`

```
r <- 10 # rows
n <- 6 # columns

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OP = {
  A <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(r*n),nrow=r)) # original data frame
  B <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=r,ncol=n)) # results
  B[,1] <- A[,1]
  for (i in 2:n) {
    maxcor <- names(which.max(sapply(A[,-1, drop=F], function(x) cor(A[, 1], x) )))
    B[,i] <- A[,1] + A[,maxcor]
    A[,1] <- B[,i]
    A[,maxcor] <- NULL
  }
},
ALEX= {
  A2 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(r*n),nrow=r)) # original data frame
  B2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=r,ncol=n)) # results
  B2[,1] <- A2[,1]
  A3 <- A2
  maxcor <- sapply(A3[,-1, drop=F], function(x) cor(A3[, 1], x) )
  cor_n <- names(A2)[order(maxcor, decreasing=T)]
  for (i in 1:length(cor_n)) {
    B2[,i+1] <- A2[,1] + apply(A2[,cor_n[1:i], drop= FALSE], 1, sum)
  }
}, times=100L)


Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
   OP 1.779013 1.806192 1.915267 1.835082 1.941329 3.585394   100   b
 ALEX 1.229343 1.253102 1.386429 1.300428 1.377404 2.925868   100  a
```

30% performance improvement... And that's with an extra copy of the data `A3 <- A2` which could obviously be removed

Comment: How do I place it outside of the loop when I have to repeat the process n-1 times?

Comment: What is not clear about it? I'd like to explain it more clearly.

Comment: The concept behind what you're trying to do makes no sense (statistically) to me. But I think I may understand the coding issue now.... Let me debug and rewrite my answer

Comment: Thank you for this method, it does indeed seem much faster. Why do you create A3, though? Wouldn't A2 suffice?

Comment: @Joseph Yes it would (as I noted). I created it in debugging and didn't care enough to fully debug and remove it... If it's helpful, please consider upvoting and accepting

Comment: @Joseph Please ask a new question. In particular, I still do not understand the motivation for the question in the first place. Please clear that up in the new question.... But I think you should be able to work out what you describe mathematically beforehand and save calculations.